# Colloquial imperative with the particle -ка

Tags: грамматика, история-языка

This form seems to be very common in modern conversational Russian, e.g.

*Пойдём-ка, покурим-ка.*

*Давайте-ка не будем пороть горячку.*

*Подожди(те)-ка!*

This form also has its more colloquial (and dialectal) counterpart with -ко:

*Слышь-ко, чё скажу...*

All in all, the -ка imperative (particle) is attested as early as in *Lermontov's* Borodino:

*Скажи-ка, дядя, ведь недаром...*

But what is the eldest attribution of this form together with its geographical area of usage?

Answer (score 3):

This particle is found in most Slavic languages, so it dates back to the Proto-Slavic times. It is attested in writing as early as in the OCS Codex Suprasliensis (Супрасльская рукопись), the middle of the 9th century. See [Vasmer](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vasmer.php?id=147&vol=2) (Vol. 2, page 147).

Comment: Right, Vasmer even said that his etimology for dialectal 'kaba'/'koba' from Veps 'kavi' rebukes Kalima's etymology from Finnish 'kapu'.

Comment: @Manjusri it seems you looked at the wrong entry. For -ка Vasmer gives Greek and Indic cognates.

Comment: @Anixx My point is that Vasmer's etymology for 'kaba'/'koba' is doubtful, and so is his etymology for this particle.

Comment: @Manjusri - 'kaba'/'koba' is a completely different topic, why are you writing about it here???

Comment: Vasmer was unable to notice the most obvious facts about Fenno-Ugric languages. His etymology of -ka dosn't seem to be more correct than that of kaba/koba.

Comment: @Manjusri - Do you mean, -ka is also borrowed from the Finno-Ugric languages?

Comment: First, we have to decide if Vasmer's etymlogy of -ka is reliable, and to which extent.

Comment: @Manjusri - If Vasmer's etymlogy isn't reliable, you have to submit some serious evidence, not just "I think it is like that". Existence of -ka in the South Slavic languges that has never been in contact with the Finno-Ugric languages is a good argument.

Comment: South Slavic languages had also been in contact with Iranian and Turkic languages. Just like Fenno-Ugric laguages had. Besides, Vasmer has missed a lot about FU consonants.

Comment: @Yellow Sky A big problem of Vasmer is that it does not provide a proto-form. Reading that x and y and z are possibly related is not what one usually expects from an etymological dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Since the particle is never stressed, it was probably mutated from -ко to -ка due to vowel reduction. Same with noun diminutive -ко (Садко, stressed) which is commonly fixed as -ка (Васька, unstressed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it has nothing to do with the question.  The question was about the earliest known attribution or usage of _-ко_ or _-ка_.

Comment: Interesting, but I think the two particles (nominal and verbal) have different origin.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Are you sure Садко is a diminutive form?